# Python Loop Perfomance issue

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have below piece of code to extract all emails from inbox:

```
def fromemailid(inbox_item_list1):
    result2, email_data = con.uid('fetch', inbox_item_list1, '(RFC822)')
    # raw_email = email_data[0][1].decode()
    raw_email = email_data[0][1].decode("ISO-8859-1")
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    email_message1 = email_message['From']
    return email_message1**

from_list_emailid = [fromemailid(item) for item in inbox_item_list]  # --- Not getting executed
```

In this case inbox_item_list contains more than a million records and code is not executed

When i am using map approach as per below it is very fast and working but again when i am trying to convert map to list same problem.

```
from_list_emailid_map = map(fromemailid, inbox_item_list)
from_list_emailid_map = list(map(fromemailid, inbox_item_list))  #--- Not getting executed**
```

Comment: What do you mean that the code is not executed?  The list is empty?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I mean it is taking lot of time and not producing the data

Comment: Have you tried running it on a single data point and seeing how long that takes?

Comment: Yes already did. With less data it is working fine.  For larger data set it is working when i am using map. I am not able to convert the data into any other form. In fact when i am looping map data it is taking time and finally getting timeout.

Comment: Your code isn't running when you create the `map` object.  You've merely created an iterator.  `fromemailid` has not been called.

Comment: You could put print statements inside your function to help debug.

Answer (score 1):

Since `inbox_item_list` contains more than 1000000 records, it'll take a lot of time and memory to convert the map object to a list. However, you can probably just leave it as a map object. Since it's an iterator, you can still access all of it's elements:

```py
from_list_emailid_map = map(fromemailid, inbox_item_list)

for email in from_list_emailid_map:
  print(email)
```

This way the iterator yields each email when needed, so you don't need to store all of them on a list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to traverse all the data records to do single operation on each record.  That is why i need to use for loop with from_list_emailid_map and it is taking lots of time